# Can an alias file be reconstructed from its data fork?

Tags: macos, alias, finder

A Mac alias file has a resource fork containing an 'alis' resource that is the alias record and probably some icon resources.  The data fork appears to contain the alias record and icon data, but I don't know exactly what the format is.  It does not appear to be a resource fork in the data fork, or AppleSingle data, or MacBinary data.

If I delete the resource fork from an alias file, the Finder in Snow Leopard cannot resolve it, but the Finder in Lion can (assuming the alias file could be resolved when intact).

I'd like to know how to repair an alias file that lacks a resource fork programmatically, on a machine where the alias cannot be resolved (e.g. because it points to a network volume that doesn't exist on this network).

Comment: I don't think you can repair it at all. At least from what I can see in 10.9 an alias without a ResourceFork contains exactly 32 bytes, against 1.7 Mb. That's way too much information loss.